# Shape derivative definition and reference?

Tags: geometry, reference-request, riemannian-geometry

I came across this paper [Variational Surface Cutting](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~kmcrane/Projects/VariationalCuts/paper.pdf) and a key concept introduced is the one of shape derivative. Is there a definition or reference I can use to get a better understanding? Is this related to Riemannian geometry, I own a couple of books on the subject there's no such definition.

Is there a reference you can suggest to look this up, together with main theorems involved in the theory maybe.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The global ideas are instead of defining the derivative of your functional ( which is defined for example on a domain $\Omega_0 \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ ) in a neighborhood of $\Omega_0$ "which have no sense because the subset of $\mathbb{R}^n$ is not a normed vector space "

you define the neighborhood of $\Omega_0$ as $\Omega= (Id+V)(\Omega_0)$  where $V$ is a vector field and $||V||\le\epsilon$ 
and by changes of variables you can define the derivative of your functional in the neighborhood of the identity, this idea belongs to Hadamard. I think you can find this notion in any book of shape optimization  please look at these references:
https://www.amazon.fr/Shape-Variation-Optimization-Geometrical-Analysis/dp/3037191783
https://books.google.co.ma/books?id=XXvNAQAACAAJ&dq=antoine+henrot&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjcmu6i_vfpAhVKRBUIHfMJBeIQ6AEIRjAD
https://www.amazon.fr/Shapes-Geometries-Analysis-Differential-Optimization/dp/0898719364

Comment: Is it "Shape optimization" the field involving these concepts then? I'm mostly looking for a friendly introduction.

Comment: Yes, it's shape optimization, I think the first 5 pages in chapter 5 in this book "Shape Variation and Optimization: A Geometrical Analysis" you will understand the idea. for a first reading, you can avoid the regularity of the vector field.